# how to use Single input value to multiple input?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

in my code   have single input fields

```
 <input name="downpaymentpc" id="downpaymentpc" class="txt" type="text" size="8" maxlength="8" onChange="javascript:downPaymentPcChanged(true);" value="<?php echo $min_fha_down_payment;?>" />
```

Now My design have four input Fields how to assign this value four input fields ? please help me

Comment: Can you setup a jsfiddle so that the problem is understood clearly?

Comment: i  have my old site have single input field value changes that single input fields.Now new design input fields have multiple input fields  .same functionality .  how to use single input fields to multiple input  same functionality ?

Comment: honestly speaking, i couldn't understand what you are asking!

Comment: Please take look now

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your form ?

Comment: @TismonVarghese  i will post my old site link and new site link here        http://www.truemortgagecalculator.com/    its old same functionality using   new design     http://dotnetportfolio.com/project/Calculator/calculate.php

Comment: @Sathish i will check after inform if its  working

Comment: @sathish Not Working

Comment: can you post your all fields?

Comment: @Sathish Take look this LInk please  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31958069/how-link-single-input-fields-split-to-separate-fields